# Kotlin T value cannot be assigned with function that returns any

Tags: generics, kotlin

so i have this code that won't compile.

```
suspend fun <T> GetContent(call: ApplicationCall) : T {
    var requestContent: T? = null

    try {
        requestContent = call.receive()
    }
    catch (exception: Exception) {
        println(exception)
    }
}
```

The problem is that `call.receive()` returns any
so i get an error saying "T? is not a subtype of Any".

So I Read about `Any` and the key concept is in the first 2 line of the documentation

"The root of the Kotlin class hierarchy. Every Kotlin class has Any as a superclass."

But it creates this paradox where T really does not inherits from `Any` because its not a class
but in the other hand it will surly be a class when using it.

I'm new to Kotlin so I guess I just not fully understand the `Any` concept or not fully understand something in the Generic concept.

Comment: `T` is `Any?` but an `Any` does not have to be `T`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably did Java before, right?
`Any` is the Kotlin equivalent to Javas `Object`, which means in Kotlin every object implicitly inherits from `Any` or in other words `Any` can be used as a placeholder for *any* possible class.

In your case you could try casting your result, I think this will work:

```
requestContent = call.receive() as T
```

This line means, you know, that `call.receive()` is indeed an Object of class `T` or a subclass of it. This will throw an error, if this assumption is false.

// Edit: A clearer example of inheritance.

Take the following example, you have a class `Animal` and two subclasses `Dog` and `Cat`. Your inheritance graph looks like this now:

```
         Animal
        /      \
       /        \
      V          V
     Dog        Cat
```

So this says: Each cat is an animal and each dog is an animal.
But if you have any animal you can't say whether it is a dog or a cat.

In your specific case, `Any` is the `Animal` class and f.e. `Dog` is your `T`. So `T` does indeed inherit from `Any`, but you don't know if it's really a `T` or maybe something else, but if you know that in this specific case it is `T`, you can cast it.

Answer (score 1):

To address the point about `Any`:

This is about nullability.

The documentation you found is talking about *classes*, but not about *types*; the distinction is subtle but important.  (Even in Java, those things aren't quite the same; for example, `List` is a class, but `List<String>` is a type.)

In Kotlin, nullability is part of the type system.  So while `Any` is the topmost class (corresponding to Java's `Object`), both `Any` and `Any?` are types: the difference being that only the latter can hold `null`.  This makes `Any` a subtype of `Any?`, and `Any?` the topmost type.

Your example has the type `T?`, which is nullable — and so not a subtype of `Any`, which isn't.

However, that's not the only thing going in your question; in the code you quoted, `T?` would have to be a *supertype* of `Any` — which it's clearly not.  (I'm also puzzled by trying to parameterise only the return value.  How is the compiler supposed to infer the actual type of `T` in each call?)

Comment: Yah I guess thats right i have to do the casting to T. Now when I understand the Any type better and the syntax I see how it does not make sense. The compiler can't just figure that out of the blue